# expand video on hover

Tags: jquery, video, angular-ui-bootstrap, dreamweaver

I'm trying to get a video to expand on hover but it's not working and I'm at my wit's end.

(using Dreameaver CC 2015 w/ bootstrap)

```js
$("#wd1").mouseenter(function() {
 vid = document.getElementById("wd1"); 
 posTop = $("#wd1").offset().top;
 posLeft = $("#wd1").offset().left;
 vidWidth = vid.clientWidth;
 vidHeight = vid.clientHeight;
 $("#wd1").remove();
 vidPlayer = document.createElement('div')
 vidPlayer.setAttribute("id", "vpId");
 vidPlayer.style.position = "relative";
 vidPlayer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.9)"
 vidPlayer.style.marginTop = posTop;
 vidPlayer.style.marginLeft = posLeft;
 vidPlayer.innerHTML = '<video src="public_html/media/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4" width="'+vidWidth+'" height="'+vidHeight+'" autoplay loop type="video.mp4">';
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(vidPlayer);
 $("#vpId").hide().fadeIn(2000);
 $("#vpId").animate({width: "100%", height: "auto"}, 500);
});
```

```css
#wd1:hover {
 z-index:1000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 50vw;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
    <div id="box"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
      <div class="row" id="vpDiv">
             <div class="col-lg-3">
      <video id="wd1" src="https://matthew-williams.000webhostapp.com/media/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4" alt="my image" width="100%" height="auto" data-video="https://matthew-williams.000webhostapp.com/media/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/1300/

Comment: Sorry to clarify, it should expand starting from the current position in the browser and ending centered vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
    #wd1:hover {
    z-index:1000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50vw;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    transform: translateX(25%) translateY(25%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(25%, 25%);
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

You can play around the values of `translateX()`, and `translateY()`.

Comment: Thank you, Jerred. Implementing these changes along with a few position, display and zIndex attributes changes, and removing some script lines, I'm left with a css :hover issue. If I use the css :hover the user mouse must follow the video in order for it to display properly, hense why I opted to use jquery to first and foremost remove the original video and create a new one starting at the original user positioning of the video in a new div and have it expand (ie only using .mouseenter() and having a close button).